# unable to install mysql-2.9.1.gem in windows 8.1 with ruby version 2.1.5

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using Ruby 2.1.5 and rest details are

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
test-unit (2.1.5.0)

and when i am installing mysql-2.9.1.gem it is giving an error as follows::

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql-2.9.1.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -llibmysql... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-libmysqllib
        --without-libmysqllib
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to gen
erate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:742:in `try_func'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:973:in `block in have_library'

        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:918:in `block in checking_for'

        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in po
stpone'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:917:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:968:in `have_library'
        from extconf.rb:27:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql-
2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.1.0
/mysql-2.9.1/gem_make.out

D:\Softwares>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when I am installing mysql gem. Maybe [this](http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html) can help.

Comment: Ruby Gems will not work properly with 64-bit version so u can install 32-bit version and it work properly.., just now i fixed..,

Comment: I actually installed a 64-bit version and it's working properly